# How to set Jupyter's env variables for VSCode's interactive Jupyter Window?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, environment-variables

In VSCode I can create a jupyter notebook via the Command Palette "Jupyter: Create Interactive Window".

How can I set the Jupyter env variables for [Jupyter directories](https://docs.jupyter.org/en/latest/use/jupyter-directories.html) so the Jupyter interactive window recognizes them?

For example, how can I set the JUPYTER_RUNTIME_DIR so the Jupyter interactive window will use it's value?